# Error while proxying request: getting credentials: exec: executable aws not found Lens

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubectl, amazon-eks

I have synced a kube config File from WSL2 to Lens on Windows and I keep getting this issues. Can someone help me resolving this issue?

[image]

Comment: Not sure why someone voted down for it... what's wrong?

Comment: I think someone gave you minus because the problem was already told in the screenshot. It first says the AWS cli executable not found and provides you also a link so that you can further analyze. To ask a question you need to at least show that you tried to solve it and after that still faced some issues.

Comment: @FuatUlugay the link and most of the error message are a red herring here, and the question is completely valid - the problem is due to how the `aws` exec is located via regular CLI in Windows (via both PATH and other extensions), and how Lens handles it (via PATH only)

Answer (score 2):

It happened with me as well after upgrading my macOS to `Sonoma 14.3`. Before that, Lens was working fine. **Solution 3 mentioned below worked for me.**

macOS: `OS Version: Sonoma 14.3 - Chip: Apple M1 Max`

Lens: `Lens: 2024.1.300751-latest - Extension API: 6.10.33 - Electron: 27.2.4 - Chrome: 118.0.5993.159 - Node: 18.17.1`

AWS CLI: `aws-cli/2.13.30 Python/3.11.6 Darwin/23.3.0 source/arm64 prompt/off`

### Possible Solutions

#### Solution 1

Ideally, adding your `aws` exe or bin in the `PATH` environment variable should fix it upon restarting both the system and the Lens app.

#### Solution 2

If your `aws` exe or bin is already in the `PATH` environment variable, then you can fix it by giving `Files and Folders` access to Lens from here: `Settings > Privacy & Security > Files and Folders > Lens`

If `Files and Folders` access is not working by default or after enabling for all files and folders or even after moving the `aws` exe or bin in one of those directories that have been allowed via `Files and Folders` and updating the `PATH` environment variable, then you have to go for solution 3.

### Solution 3 (WORKED FOR ME)

If solution 1 and 2 didn't work, then you can fix it by giving `Full Disk Access` to Lens from here: `Settings > Privacy & Security > Full Disk Access > Lens`. Though, it is not recommended.

Reference Screenshot for this solution can be found below:

[image: Reference Screenshot - Settings > Privacy & Security > Full Disk Access > Lens]

Answer (score 0):

On Windows it often happens because Lens/OpenLens might use only user-profile `PATH` variable to resolve AWS CLI exec location, but your regular CLI (`cmd.exe` e.g.) uses both system `PATH` and user `PATH` together - so after e.g. MSI install it'll work in `cmd`/`ps`, but not in Lens/OpenLens terminal nor as its dependent command.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/v1/userguide/install-windows.html#awscli-install-windows-path describes the easiest solution in a good way, but the complete answer is that you either need to

- add the directory in which AWS CLI `aws.exe` resides to `PATH` user (per-profile) variables, or
- provide a simple `aws.bat` to any directory that's already in your user (per-profile) `PATH` that would contain just

  ```
  @aws %*
  ```

  , since this will allow to trigger the use of the other path-finding methods from the batch shell itself (which is basically equivalent of what `cmd.exe` provides).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue where OpenLens stopped being able to connect to the various clusters configured, complaining about not locating aws.
Nothing had changed, unless some Windows update was involved.
I checked all the settings, along the lines of similar questions about PATH location for aws - though its location had not changed.
I hate doing this as I like to understand the problem  - but I ended up with a reboot and it started working again.
It's a horrible solution since it does not identify the actual problem.